# How to disable/enable the allowinsert in telerik radscheduler

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radscheduleview

I have develop a Telerik Radscheduler in that i have write the code like below in that i want disable/Enable the perticuler time-slot for an event,in this disable is working fine but enable not working i can't understand why it is not enable to allow-insert.please help me where i need to change to resolve this problem...

```
        protected void RadScheduler1_TimeSlotCreated1(object sender, TimeSlotCreatedEventArgs e)
  {

    //Getting Business hour time
    mybusinesscalendarEntities objEntity = new mybusinesscalendarEntities();
    var Result = from bhours in objEntity.businesshours where bhours.BusinessId == businessid select bhours;
    if (Result.Count() > 0)
    {
        var Hours = (from bhours in objEntity.businesshours where bhours.BusinessId == businessid select bhours).First();


        //Get particular day businee hour timings and disable the time slot 

        string Day = System.DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        if (Day == "Monday")
        {
            string WorkDay = Hours.MondayFromTime.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            string WorkDayStart = WorkDay.Remove(WorkDay.Length - 2, 2);
            string WorkDayEnd = Hours.MondayToTime.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            string WorkDayEndTime = WorkDayEnd.Remove(WorkDayEnd.Length - 2, 2);
            if ((e.TimeSlot.Start.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.Parse(WorkDayStart.Trim())) || (e.TimeSlot.Start.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.Parse(WorkDayEndTime.Trim())))
            {
                e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "Disabled";
                RadScheduler1.ReadOnly = true;
            }

            else

            {

                RadScheduler1.ReadOnly = false;
                RadScheduler1.AllowInsert = true;
                RadScheduler1.AllowEdit = true;
                RadScheduler1.AllowDelete = true;

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If when your last timeslot is created (last time event is fired) this part evaluates to true.

```
        if ((e.TimeSlot.Start.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.Parse(WorkDayStart.Trim())) || (e.TimeSlot.Start.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.Parse(WorkDayEndTime.Trim())))
        {
            e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "Disabled";
            RadScheduler1.ReadOnly = true;
        }
```

Then your entire scheduler will be in read only mode.  This means no editing inserting deleting moving etc.

Your intention seems to be to disabled specific timeslots.  I dont think you intend to set these properties in this particular event.

```
            RadScheduler1.ReadOnly = false;
            RadScheduler1.AllowInsert = true;
            RadScheduler1.AllowEdit = true;
            RadScheduler1.AllowDelete = true;
```

Test by commenting out the lines that set the readonly, allowinster, allowedit, allowdelete properties since they are not per timeslot, rather for  the entire scheduler